# Writing JPA repository JUnit where one repository is dependent on Other

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-data-jpa

consider an example, I have two entity as below

1. Attribute.java

   ```
   @Entity
        @Table(name = "attribute")
        public class Attribute {
           @Id
           @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
           @Getter private Long id;

       @Column(name="name")
       @Getter private String name;    

       @Column(name = "source")
       @Getter private String source;

       protected Attribute(){}
       public Attribute(final String name, final String source) {
           this.name = name;
           this.source = source;
       }


   }
   ```
2. AttributeGroup.java

   ```
   @Entity
       @Table(name = "attribute_group")
       public class AttributeGroup {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Getter private Long id;

       @Column(name="name")
       @Getter private String name;

       @Column(name = "value")
       @Getter private String value;

       @Getter
       @Column(name="attribute_id", nullable=false)
       protected Long attributeId;

       @Getter
       @OneToOne(optional=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name="attribute_id",  updatable=false, insertable=false,  referencedColumnName="id")
       private Attribute attribute;

       protected AttributeGroup(){}
   }
   ```

Two repository

1. AttributeRepository.java

   `public interface AttributeRepository{}`
2. AttributeGroupRepository.java

   ```
   public interface AttributeGroupRepository {

   /**
    * find list of Groups by attribute name
    * @param attribute
    * @return
    */
   List<AttributeGroup> findByAttribute(Attribute attribute);


   }
   ```

AttributeGroupRepositoryTest.java

```
<pre><code>@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@DatabaseSetup(AttributeGroupRepositoryTest.DATASET)
@DatabaseTearDown(type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT, value = { AttributeGroupRepositoryTest.DATASET })
public class AttributeGroupRepositoryTest {
    protected static final String DATASET = "classpath:/attribute-group-test-data.xml";

    @Autowired
    private AttributeGroupRepository groupRepository;

    @Test
    public void findByAttributes(){
        Attribute attribute=new Attribute("Data","abc");
        List<AttributeGroup> groups = groupRepository.findByAttribute(attribute);

        assertThat(groups.isEmpty(), Matchers.is(false));
        assertThat(groups.size(), Matchers.equalTo(2));
        assertThat(groups.stream().findFirst().get().getId(), Matchers.equalTo(5L));
        assertThat(groups.stream().findFirst().get().getName(), Matchers.equalTo("GROUP1"));
        assertThat(groups.stream().findFirst().get().getValue(), Matchers.equalTo("HW"));
        assertThat(groups.stream().findFirst().get().getAttribute().getId(), Matchers.equalTo(3L));
        assertThat(groups.stream().findFirst().get().getAttribute().getName(), Matchers.equalTo("Data"));
        assertThat(groups.stream().findFirst().get().getAttribute().getSource(), Matchers.equalTo("abc"));
    }

}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
   <lima_attribute id="1" name="Issuer Ultimate Parent Name" source="VENTURE"/>
   <lima_attribute id="2" name="Currency" source="abc"/>
   <lima_attribute id="3" name="Data" source="abc"/>
   <lima_attribute_group id="1" name="CurrencyGroup" value="AUS" attribute_id="2"/>
   <lima_attribute_group id="2" name="CurrencyGroup" value="GBP" attribute_id="2"/>
   <lima_attribute_group id="3" name="CurrencyGroup" value="BHD" attribute_id="2"/>
   <lima_attribute_group id="4" name="CurrencyGroup" value="AFA" attribute_id="2"/>
   <lima_attribute_group id="5" name="GROUP1" value="HW" attribute_id="3"/>
   <lima_attribute_group id="6" name="GROUP1" value="VOL" attribute_id="3"/>
</dataset>
```

The above test case throws an exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.attribute.Attribute; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.attribute.Attribute

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.entity.attribute.Attribute
```

As this test is dependent on Attribute repository and as Junit's are unit test cases and I don't want to use attribute repository.

Is any other way to mock other repository data?

Comment: The problem seems to be the Attribute object you create and pass to the find method. Can you rewrite the method to findByAttributeName and just pass the name and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way without using other repository how we can execute the test case.

replacing below line:

```
List<AttributeGroup> groups = groupRepository.findByAttribute(attribute);
```

with

```
List<AttributeGroup> groups = groupRepository.findByAttributeNameAndAttributeSource("Data","abc");
```

Answer (score -1):

you are searching a object which is not persisted in the repository,please find  the attribute from the AttributeRepository first,and then search the returned attribute in the attribute group repository!

```
Attribute attribute=attributeRepository.findByNameAndSource("Data",Source);
if(attribute!=null){
   List<AttributeGroup> groups = groupRepository.findByAttribute(attribute);
}
```

Comment: as in `Junit` there no dependency on other class so actually i don't want to use `attributerepository` here. Any other way you can suggest me to mock data.